# Confunsion over active and passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, indian-english

Look at [the lines under the point "Health Concerns"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c3w1.jpg). In this line there is a line which reads

> #### Health concerns
>
> "A health survey was conducted with the local people... it found that diseases like cholera, dysentery, and skin disease were predominant in the post-Ganga Sagar Mela period," observed a paper titled [...]

It is an news article published by an eminent newspaper. My question is should it not be like this?

> "it **is** found that diseases like cholera,dysentery, and skin disease were predominant in the post Ganga Sagar Mela period"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"it found" is actually active voice as the pronoun "it" refers to the health survey which found that diseases...

The passive structure would have looked something like this:

```
Diseases like cholera, dysentery, and skin disease were found to be 
predominant in the post-Ganga Sagar Mela period by the health survey.
```